# Width of a rectangle

Tags: html, css, textarea

What's the code for making a rectangle as wide as the screen?

But for a `<textarea>` that has some writing in front of it and you want the actual textbox to go to the end of the screen?

http://jsfiddle.net/79CBq/2/ `enter code here`

if you pull the result page as much as possible in the left way, you'll see that the textarea doesn't reach the other side.

Comment: Can you explain better your issue? With some code.

Comment: Clarify your question

Comment: Also show relevant CSS code, please!

Comment: see the original post :) thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS:

```
textarea {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: consider changing it to `textarea.rectangle`

Comment: I removed the rectangle completely because at this person's inferred level, classes are probably unnecessary baggage. I would also add @user2294266 that a simple, fun, YouTube CSS tutorial will help you a lot.